# Looping over multiple input sources pairing one by one

Tags: bash, loops

**Requirements**

Two files: A and W.

Need to pair  the first line of file A with the first of file W; second to second, third to third ...

**Example:**

```
>>> File A 
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
text7
text8
text9

>>> File W 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**What I've done:**

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r a <&3; do
   while read w<&4; do
       echo "add host name $a ipv4-address $w"
   done 4<W
done 3<A
```

But the output iterates first line of A with the all the lines from W:

```
add host name text1 ipv4-address 1
add host name text1 ipv4-address 2
add host name text1 ipv4-address 3
add host name text1 ipv4-address 4
add host name text1 ipv4-address 5
add host name text1 ipv4-address 6
add host name text1 ipv4-address 7
add host name text1 ipv4-address 8
add host name text1 ipv4-address 9
add host name text2 ipv4-address 1
add host name text2 ipv4-address 2
add host name text2 ipv4-address 3
add host name text2 ipv4-address 4
add host name text2 ipv4-address 5
add host name text2 ipv4-address 6
add host name text2 ipv4-address 7
add host name text2 ipv4-address 8
add host name text2 ipv4-address 9
add host name text3 ipv4-address 1
add host name text3 ipv4-address 2
add host name text3 ipv4-address 3
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:

```
file1=A
file2=W

while read -r line1 && read -r line2 <&3 ; do
  printf "add host name %s ipv4-address %s\n" "${line1}" "${line2}"
done <${file1} 3<${file2}
```

But there is no failure handling included, also no test for the correct number of lines in both files.

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
paste a b|awk '{print "add host name " $1 " ipv4-address " $2}'
add host name text1 ipv4-address 1
add host name text2 ipv4-address 2
add host name text3 ipv4-address 3
add host name text4 ipv4-address 4
add host name text5 ipv4-address 5
add host name text6 ipv4-address 6
add host name text7 ipv4-address 7
add host name text8 ipv4-address 8
add host name text9 ipv4-address 9
```